# Different conventions for main() in C

Tags: c, program-entry-point

My only exposure to programming has been Java,where I have not encountered (up to now) different conventions for writing the main method.I have been following to sources for learning c (K&R AND C Programming A Modern Approach) where they use very different forms of the main method (function).

**K&R version up to now:**

```
main() {
    blah blah blah;
}
```

**C Programming A Modern Approach**

```
int main() {
    blah blah blah;
    return 0;
}
```

**OR**

```
int main() {
    blah blah blah; 
    //returns nothing
}
```

To make matters more confusing I have seen people do :

```
int main(void) {
    blah blah blah;
}
```

while they either returned 0 or did not. 
I don't in my very uneducated assumption think this is only a standards issue but maybe something a bit more conceptual or deep.
Could someone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: @SuvarnaPattayil not sure about that. It's **very close** and might very well be a duplicate, but at least this question specifically asks about styles found in some sources, including K&R ...

Comment: @FelixPalmen It's a canonical dupe - any possible answer to this question is already there or linked to there.

Comment: **C** Language does not have Methods.

Comment: Another variant you will often see is returning the constant `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `EXIT_FAILURE` from `<stdlib.h>`, rather than the magic number `0`.

Comment: Some of the answers mention that the standard gives compilers permission to add “implementation-defined” alternative forms for `main()`. Many compilers allow the return type of `main()` to be `void`, some I’ve used allow it to take a third argument (a list of environment variables), and some allow it to be called with only one argument.  None of these options strictly conform to the standard.

Answer (score 14):

- K&R style is outdated and isn't correct according to the C standard any more.
- Valid signatures are

  ```
  int main(void)
  ```

  and

  ```
  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  ```

  or, equivalent because an array type in a function is adjusted to a pointer type anyways:

  ```
  int main(int argc, char **argv)
  ```
- The signature

  ```
  int main()
  ```

  happens to be valid as well, because an empty argument list means *any number of arguments, that aren't described* *). AFAIK, this is subject to change, so don't write it this way. Writing `void` is how you express *this function doesn't take arguments* in C.
- Implementations of C are free to provide other *implementation-defined* entry points. But the two I listed above are the only ones guaranteed by the standard.
- C99 introduced a special rule for `main()` that states if the function doesn't return anything, a value of `0` is returned implicitly. So **only in main**, you can skip the `return`. My advice is: don't. It's just confusing. But this is an opinion.

---

<sup>*) note this is **different** in C++, where nothing between the parantheses **indeed** means: no arguments.</sup>

Comment: *C99 introduced a special rule for `main()` that states if the function doesn't return anything, a value of 0 is returned implicitly. So **only in main**, you can skip the `return`. My advice is: don't. It's just confusing. But this is an opinion.*  But it's not just an opinion as there are still [compilers that don't fully implement C99.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fa17bcdd-7165-4645-a676-ef3797b95918/details-on-c99-support-in-msvc?forum=vcgeneral)

Comment: @Andrew Henle Microsoft is not a very good example as microsoft does not care about C anymore.

Comment: Also `int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *env[])` where the third is a `NULL` terminated array of environment variable strings - IDK if this is standard.

Comment: @WeatherVane that's POSIX (edit: not even specified, but typical in POSIX systems) and by means of the standard falls in the "implementation defined" category, very much like windows' `WinMain()` and friends.

Comment: @PeterJ *Microsoft is not a very good example as microsoft does not care about C anymore.* In my opinion that makes Microsoft a very, very good (bad?) example.  If Microsoft is going to claim to have a C compiler, they should at least *try* to meet an almost-twenty-year-old standard.

Comment: @Andrew Henle they re going to remove C support soon I think. They only do the minimum necessary needed by the C++ standard. Even setting to compile as C file is hidden deep in the VS17 configurations options. The option to create the C project was removed. And they claim that they have C++ compiler which allows compilation of the C projects

Answer (score 5):

Pre-standardized versions of C (known as K&R C) had the concept of a default type of `int` if none was given.  So in K&R this:

```
main() {
```

Is the same as:

```
int main() {
```

As for the difference between `int main()` and  `int main(void)`, an empty parameter list means the function takes an unspecified number of parameters while `(void)` as a parameter list means the function takes no parameters.  The former is acceptable, but the latter is preferred as it is more explicit.

Regarding the use of the `return` statement, a function with a non-void return type **must** use `return` to return a value, *except* (starting with the C99 standard) for the `main` function.  In the case of `main`, a missing `return` statement implies a return value of 0.

Because the implicit `return 0` for main was added in C99, you'll see some code that explicitly returns and some that doesn't depending on which version of the standard the programmer is conforming to.

Comment: How can you NOT specify how many arguments a function takes ? By using int main(empty) you are saying it can take arguments,but how can this be the case if the function does not know the type or the amount of arguments it is supposed to take ?

Comment: @AliMan by writing nothing between the parantheses in the declaration.

Answer (score 4):

There are two *standard* signatures for `main` as of the latest C language standard:

```
int main( void ) // void indicates "takes no arguments"
```

and

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) // or char **argv, it means the same thing in this context
```

The names `argc` and `argv` are arbitrary; you can use different names if you wish.

Implementations *may* provide additional valid signatures for `main` - check your compiler documentation.

If your program does not take any command line arguments, use the first form, otherwise use the second.

C function declaration and definition syntax has evolved a bit over time, which is why different references use different conventions.

**Implicit Typing**

First of all, C originally allowed for implicit `int` declarations - if the compiler saw a function definition or declaration without a type specifier, it assumed the function returned `int`:

```
foo(); // modern equivalent: int foo( void )
```

This was allowed up until the 1999 standard, although was considered bad style by most of us long before then.

The `void` keyword was not introduced until the 1989 standard.  As a type specifier, it indicates a type with no values.  As an identifier in a function parameter list, it indicates that the function takes no arguments.

Before the introduction of the `void` keyword, there was no good way (other than documentation) to distinguish between functions that returned a value you were meant to use vs. functions that just executed some action. Some of us used the "implicit `int`" convention to indicate those functions weren't meant to return anything meaningful:

```
foo();     /* returns int, but return value not meant to be used */
int bar(); /* returns int, return value meant to be used */
```

Again, this was just a convention, and far from universal. Now we'd use the `void` keyword:

```
void foo(); /* does not return a value */
int bar();  /* returns int */
```

**Function Prototype Syntax**

Originally, a function *definition* looked something like this:

```
foo( bar, bletch, blurga )
  int bar;
  double bletch;
  char *blurga;
{
  /* function body */
}
```

The parameter list only specified the *names* of the parameters, not their types; that was done in a separate set of declarations between the function declarator and the opening `{` of the function body.  A function that took no arguments had an empty identifier list in the function *definition*:

```
blah( )  
{
  /* function body */
}
```

Function *declarations* only specified the name and return type of the function; it didn't specify the parameters at all:

```
foo( ); /* no bar, bletch, or blurga */
```

An empty identifier list in a function *declaration* indicates that the function takes an *unspecified* number of arguments, not zero arguments.  The compiler could check that the return type of the function *call* was being used correctly, but it could not check that the number and types of parameters in the call were correct.

The 1989 language standard introduced the concept of function *prototype* syntax, where the type of each parameter was specified along with its name in the parameter list:

```
foo( int bar, double bletch, char *blurga )
{
  /* function body */
}
```

This applied to *both* the function declaration and definition:

```
foo( int bar, double bletch, char *blurga );
```

This change allowed the compiler to check that the number and types of parameters in a function call were correct, along with the return type. In addition, the `void` keyword could be used in the parameter list to indicate that the function took *no* parameters, in both the definition *and* declaration:

```
blah( void ); /* declaration, returns int, takes no parameters */

blah( void )  /* definition */
{
   /* function body */
}
```

So yeah, depending on which language revision you're working against, `main` would be written differently:

K&R:

```
main()                            main( argc, argv )
{                                   int argc;
  ...                               char *argv[];
}                                 {
                                    ...
                                  }
```

C89:

```
main( void )                      main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{                                 {
  ...                               ...
}                                 }
```

C99 and later:

```
int main( void )                  int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{                                 {
  ...                               ...
}                                 }
```

Comment: Thanks.I cannot up vote your answer due to restrictions on my account.But you truly illuminated my understanding.

Comment: Excellent answer. You know this, of course, but to add a bit of context: the old-fashioned, any-number-of-unchecked-arguments kind of function was replaced by the *varargs* style function. People learning C will first encounter this as `int printf( const char* format, ... );` which has any number of arguments of any type *after the first one*. Compilers are now smart enough to type-check the arguments of `printf()`. This was the original use case for being able to call functions with a different number and type of arguments. It’s now done another, source-compatible way.

Answer (score 3):

C standard defines signature for `main` either as

```
int main(void)
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

Adding `return 0;` as a last statement in `main` function is optional.
Standard also says about some implementation defined prototype. `int main()` is accepted by [GCC](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/argc-and-argv.html) compiler.

`main()` is an old school prototype and almost deprecated.